# Salesforce1 HTML select onChange function not working in Salesforce1 IPAD app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, html5

I have created an HTML5 VF page to be used in Salesforce1 app. It has a select list Called Event Name with values:

- Presentation
- Lecture
- Other

There is another text field called Type. This has to be displayed only if 'Event Name' is Presentation. Otherwise it should be hidden. I implemented it using `onChange` event for the select list. It works perfectly if I run the page using https://[InstanceName].salesforce.com/one/one.app

But when I try to access the page using Salesforce1 IPAD app the page hangs. Kindly Suggest. Code:

**HTML**

```
<select name="EventName" id="EventName" data-mini="false" onChange='CheckEvent(this.value)'>

               <option value="Presentation">Presentation</option> 
           <option value="Lecture">Lecture</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option> 
</select>

<input name="Type" for="Type" id="Type" style='display:block;'> </input>
```

**JS**

```
function CheckEvent(val){

     var element=document.getElementById('Type');

     if(val=='Presentation'){

       element.style.display='block';
     }
     else{

         element.value='';
       element.style.display='none';
     }
    }
```